# What's the most efficient way to search a list millions of times?

Tags: python

I know the simple way to search would be to have a list containing the strings, and just do `if string in list`, but it gets slow, and I've heard dictionary keys practically have no slowdown with large sets due to the fact they're not ordered.

However, I don't need any extra information relating to the items, so it feels a little wrong making a dictionary just to hold the keys and set the values to `None`.

Is there something I can use that acts like dictionary keys speed wise, but acts like a list?

Here's a quick example:

```
import time, random

totalRange = 100000
searchFor = 5000

#Create a list of 10 million characters
searchableList = []
for i in range( totalRange ):
    searchableList.append( random.randint( 0, totalRange ) )

#Create dictonary with keys set to 'None'
searchableDict = {}
for i in searchableList:
    searchableDict[i] = None

searchableSet = set( searchableList )

#Search list
startTime = time.time()
numberMatches = 0
for number in range( searchFor ):
    if number in searchableList:
        numberMatches += 1
print numberMatches, time.time()-startTime

#Search dictionary keys
startTime = time.time()
numberMatches = 0
for number in range( searchFor ):
    if number in searchableDict:
        numberMatches += 1
print numberMatches, time.time()-startTime

#Search set
startTime = time.time()
numberMatches = 0
for number in range( searchFor ):
    if number in searchableSet:
        numberMatches += 1
print numberMatches, time.time()-startTime
```

Here are the time outputs:

```
List: 18.8 seconds
Set: 0.002 seconds
Dictionary: 0.0009 seconds
```

Even though set is a lot faster than a list, the dictionary is still twice as fast, so I'm wondering if there's anything else I don't know about. Using a dictionary wouldn't be too bad, I'd just imagine there was a cleaner way to do it than `dictionary[key]=None`.

Edit based on iCodez's answer:

Tests when `totalRange=1000000` and `searchFor=50000` (10x higher):

```
List = 20 minutes and still going
Dictionary = 0.023 seconds
Set = 0.02 seconds
Set.intersection = 0.008 seconds
```

With more calculations it seems sets and dictionaries have a very similar efficiency, but the `set.intersetion` way is clearly a lot better.

Comment: The cleanest, clearest, most obvious way to do it is with sets. It's unfortunate that your current implementations seems to have a slight penalty for that, but it really doesn't look like that much to worry about. If you can tolerate a little fuzzyness, a Bloom filter might be a good fit.

Comment: Use a set. Your time difference is negligible, and it's conceptually the right data structure.

Comment: .002 vs .0009 is way too small to actually say which is faster. That's well within the limits of using a timer like you're doing.

Comment: you should use timeit module for small times like that ...

Comment: Some quick tests confirm that `dicts` are _slightly_ faster on my machine. (Only by about 10%.) On the other hand, on average, a set will use less memory than a dictionary.

Comment: Im curious if using `set.intersection` (since thats basically what he wants) would likely be much faster than iterating (regardless of the fact that set is a more natural datastructure for this problem)

Comment: FWIW some timeit tests I just did had *sets* being slightly faster.  But I'd be very surprised if Joran's suggestion of `set.intersection` wasn't *much* faster still (trading off memory for speed.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) in this case.  Sets have the same lookup time as dictionaries ([constant](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)), but they consist of individual items instead of key/value pairs.  So, you get the same speed for less memory and a better representation of the data.

---

Also, you would improve efficiency by using [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) instead of a for-loop:

```
numberMatches = len(searchableSet.intersection(xrange(searchFor)))
```

You'll notice too that I replaced `range` with [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange).  This keeps Python from building an unnecessary list and thereby wasting memory.

Comment: They have the same asymptotic lookup time, yes, but OP's timing suggests that the dict lookup is faster for his data for some reason.

Comment: @senshin a `set` is pretty much a `dict` with values set to `None`

Comment: since he is calculating the number of intersections using `set.intersection` would likely be faster

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Good idea.  I'll add it.

Comment: I am getting these kind of results - dict:0.00069 / set:0.00066 / set.intersection:0.00027 (averaged over ten runs). Python 2.7 on OSX 10.10 / 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7. Intersection version typically over twice as fast.

Comment: Thanks, though do you have any idea why the set the wasn't as efficient in my example? The increment was just a temporary thing to make sure the results were accurate, but the `set.intersection` does look extremely useful, and I also wasn't sure of the use of `xrange` before so that's helped too :)

Comment: Also, just tried it for speed and got slightly different results to foundry, pushing up the numbers of my code to 1000000 and 20000 gives 0.008 for dictionary, 0.005 for set, and 0.002 for set.intersection

Comment: its clearly going to have some dependency on your CPU and other various hardware factors ...

Comment: @Peter - `set.intersection` is written in C, so all Python has to do is lookup the name and then the rest is done by C.  Your code however was having Python do most of the work, which will almost always be slower.  Also, `range` was building a rather large list, which wastes time.

Comment: Ahh right thanks, that's useful to know, I'll keep that in mind if I end up looking for any other solutions relating to faster execution

Answer (score 4):

use

```
a_dict = dict.fromkeys(my_text.split())
```

Comment: Thanks, that's so much neater than my method of doing it, but it still has the problem of being a dictionary with all the keys given a value of `None`, I more meant totally avoiding that and having a list that acts like a dictionary in terms of speed :)

Comment: I dont disagree that set is the appropriate data structure ... this was just answering the question about a better way of `d[key] = None`

Comment: I wasn't aware you could do it this way so it's still very useful aha, I tend to use loops to do everything so it's good to see better ways of doing things :)